# Three-dimensional array from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I am a beginner to Android programming looking for advice/constructive criticism. I am using the code attached below in order to generate a three-dimensional array from the contents of the strings.xml file. Once the array has been generated, I have additional code (not attached) that picks a certain value from the array and uses it to perform some calculations and display a result within a textview. Is my approach good or is there a better way to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance.

Here is a small sample of the contents of strings.xml (there are about 50 string arrays with anywhere from 4 to about 150 items, with each item containing 10 integers or decimal values):

```
<string-array name="state1">
    <item>686, 33, 22, 93, 76, 38, 45, 52, 2, 0.55</item>
    <item>600, 34, 25, 92, 76, 36, 43, 50, 2, 0.51</item>
    <item>774, 33, 28, 91, 74, 28, 35, 42, 2, 0.43</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="state2">
    <item>20, 52, 23, 57, 53, -19, -13, -6, 1, 90</item>
    <item>289, 67, -38, 73, 58, -26, -19, -12, 2, 24</item>
    <item>2156, 68, -35, 66, 53, -36, -29, -22, 2, 77</item>
    <item>131, 61, -4, 68, 57, -19, -12, -6, 1, 14</item>
    <item>138, 61, -7, 70, 58, -19, -12, -5, 1, 11</item>
    <item>194, 61, -9, 71, 58, -23, -16, -9, 1, 13</item>
    <item>342, 61, -13, 71, 58, -20, -14, -7, 2, 13</item>
    <item>112, 55, 20, 69, 59, -13, -6, 0, 1, 8</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        int i, j, k;
        float[][][] weatherData = new float[60][200][10];
        for (i = 1; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            int arrayID = res.getIdentifier("state" + i,"array",getPackageName());
            String[] stateData = res.getStringArray(arrayID);
            int m = stateData.length;
            for (j = 0; j < m ; j++)
            {
                String[] dataValues = stateData[j].split(",");
                int n = dataValues.length;
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    weatherData[i-1][j][k] = Float.parseFloat(dataValues[k]);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v("value", ""+weatherData[1][14][9]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using Java, you need to learn something of OO, like encapsulation... That will help you to make your code more easy to read.

Comment: Optimisation tip: it looks like you are doing some calculations on some static data. Instead you could store the result of the calculations so you dont have to it again. You can use a java class for this and store the arrays as constants.

Comment: @KNeerajLal The data in the three-dimensional array consists of all constant values and the activity which would contain this code would pick just a single value from the array and just once.

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee I do plan on using encapsulation once I decide on how to create the array with all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be not to use the Android string arrays here. It looks messy and it's clearly not designed for usage with 3D data.I would rather use a plain text file in your case.

The format of the file could be something like that `x,y,z:value` e.g.:

```
0,0,1:0.5
0,0,2:2
1,1,1:12.1
```

Raw data can be placed in `/res/raw/data.txt`, and accessed this way:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // process single line here
}
```

Comment: I think a little bit of additional information might be useful. In the activity just before this one, the user is given the opportunity to select a country (using a spinner). This selection updates a second spinner with the list of states for that country. Once the user picks a state, a third spinner is updated with a list of cities in that state. I plan on having a 3-D array for each country. Using your suggestion, it appears that I would need 50 raw data text files containing the numerical data corresponding to each state/city (for the USA). Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you! I tried this out and I think it's a better option.